# class template, expected constructor, destructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

ok, so here's my header file (or at least part of it):

```
template<class T>

class List
{
public:
.
:
List& operator= (const List& other);
.
:
private:
.
:
};
```

and here is my .cc file:

```
template <class T>
List& List<T>::operator= (const List& other)
{
    if(this != &other)
    {
        List_Node * n = List::copy(other.head_);
        delete [] head_;
        head_ = n;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

on the line `List& List<T>::operator= (const List& other)` I get the compilation error "Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '&' token". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Template class definition must be in the header file. Have a look at this question for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type `List&` can't be used without the template arguments.  It needs to be `List<T>&`.

```
template <class T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator= (const List& other)
{
   ...
}
```

But note that even after you fix this syntax error, you'll have linker problems because template function definitions need to be placed in the header file.  See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for more information.